# How view the current page in the frame in html?

Tags: php, html, iframe

I'm trying to create the `frame` in my web page.
To create the frame, I'm using the tag called `<IFRAME>`.
My file name is `Testing.html`. 
For example:

```
<IFRAME src="Sample.html" style="width:800px; height: 250px; float:right; border:none"></IFRAME> <br>
```

When I give another file as `src` then the frame will work properly.
But if I tried to give the current file as `src` It has not working.
For example:

```
<IFRAME src="Testing.html" style="width:800px; height: 250px; float:right; border:none"></IFRAME> <br>
```

The above example has not working. What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: meybe you don't need ./

Comment: If I give like that, Why it not visible?

Comment: did you try without ./ , because testing.html is in the same directory

Comment: Yes I tried without ./, Even though its not working.

Comment: Testing.html would have a new Frame with a reference to Testing.html. Do you want to introduce a loop?

Comment: yes, like a loop, But it has to iterate only one time.

Comment: You should try the full path where that file is located. For example "/folder/folder/folder/file-name.html" or "https://example.com/folder/folder/folder/file-name.html"

Comment: Yes, I tried that too, But it has not working. The frame will be empty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-iframe-element):

> If there exists an ancestor browsing context whose active document's address, ignoring fragment identifiers, is equal to url, then abort these steps.

So, you can't. HTML forbids recursive framing and requires browsers to abort at the first sign of it.